# simple Image feature camparision taking too much time

Tags: matlab, image-processing, optimization, computer-vision, vectorization

I have the following matlab code for comparison for histogram features of image; features are basically 3 dimentional arrays

```
for i=1:1:26
    for j=1:1:26
        s1=sum(image1(i,j,:));
        s2=sum(image2(i,j,:));
        if(s1>2 && s2>2)
            for k=1:1:31
                if image1(i,j,k)~=0 && image2(i,j,k)~=0  
                    d = d + ((image1(i,j,k) - image2(i,j,k))^2)/ (image1(i,j,k) + image2(i,j,k));
                end
            end
            count=count+1;
        end
    end
end
```

code is giving satisfactory result, but the problem is it is taking to much time about (1 second) in matlab on my machine, I really need to optimize it, any kind of help or suggestion to do it other way is welcome

Comment: What is the size of the image? and the specs of your computer?

Comment: Is `d` initialized as zero at some place? Is `count` initialized as zero at some other place?

Comment: size of image is 208x208  ,and Intel® Core™ i5-3337U CPU @ 1.80GHz × 4, memory-3.7 gb , os-ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @Divakar d and count is initialized to 0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one [`vectorized`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) approach -

```
%// Sum elements of image1 & image2 along the third dimension corresponding 
%// to s1 and s2 in the original loopy code
s1v = sum(image1,3);
s2v = sum(image2,3);

%// Pre-calculate all image1,image2 operations that lead to the calculation
%// of d in the original code
allvals = ((image1 - image2).^2)./(image1 + image2);

%// Calculate the first conditional values for the corresponding IF conditional
%// statement in original post - "if(s1>2 && s2>2)"
cond1 = s1v>2 & s2v>2

%// Sum all satisfying first conditional values for getting "count"
count = sum(cond1(:))

%// Calculate the second conditional values for the corresponding IF conditional
%// statement in original post - "if image1(i,j,k)~=0 && image2(i,j,k)~=0"
cond2 = image1~=0 & image2~=0;

%// Map both cond1 and cond2 onto allvals to select specific elements from
%// it and then sum those up for the final output, d
d = sum(cond1(:).'*reshape(cond2.*allvals,[],size(allvals,3)))
```

The last line could be calculated with `bsxfun` instead like so -

```
d = sum(allvals(bsxfun(@and,cond1,cond2)))
```

Comment: When I read this question, I **knew** you would come up with an answer. The surprising thing is that there is no `bsxfun`. in it. :-)

Comment: @kkuilla Well there was for the calulation of `d`, but I removed it at the last moment :)

Comment: @Divakar value of d is coming Nan because some values of image1 and image2 are 0

Comment: @Gitesh Let us know the speedups you might be getting with the proposed approaches?

Comment: @Gitesh Very Kool! Thanks for the upate!

Answer (score 3):

The golden rule of speeding up matlab code is to avoid for loops and use vectorised code and matrices where possible.  It's possible to do this calculation very quickly using vectorisation and logical indices.  I've tested the following in octave and it works fine and is very quick - you may need to replace != with ~= for matlab compatibility.  Adjust n and p to make testing less painful (or delete the first 4 lines) and initialise d to whatever you prefer.

```
n=26; 
p=31; 
i1=1.5*rand(n,n,p); i2=1.5*rand(n,n,p); 
s1=sum(i1,3); s2=sum(i2,3); 
indices=((s1>2) & (s2>2)) & ((i1!=0) &(i2!=0)); 
d=0; 
d=d+sum(sum(  (  (i1(indices)-i2(indices)).^2  )  ./ (i1(indices)+i2(indices)) )), 
count=sum(sum( (s1 > 2) & (s2 > 2) ) )
```